# Is it possible to pass additional custom user data to custom ASP.NET Membership provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm implementing my custom Membership provider and I need to implement some additional fields (such as first name, last name, country, etc).

I know I can extend MembershipUser class and cast to it when I return aa user object from my provider. The thing which I can't find how to do and if it is possible to do is how to actually pass these custom properties to my provider when I'm creating a new user `Membership.CreateUser(...)` during user registration.

Is it possible at all? If yes, how it can be done?

Thanks

UPDATE

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx) says

> However, this overload will not be called by the Membership class or
>   controls that rely on the Membership class, such as the
>   CreateUserWizard control. To call this method from an application,
>   cast the MembershipProvider instance referenced by the Membership
>   class as your custom membership provider type, and then call your
>   CreateUseroverload directly.

`Membership` in this case is a reference to a instance of the class and at the same time it is a class by itself.

Neither

```
((CustomMembershipProvider)Membership).CreateUser(...);
```

nor

```
(CustomMembershipProvider)Membership.CreateUser(...);
```

works.

How should I cast it in this case?

UPDATE: See my answer.

Comment: yes you can create a custom membership provider here is a MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx

Comment: That probably should have been an answer, not a comment. +1 anyways.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this article, but it doesn't really show how to pass additional fields to provider. So basically When I do `Membership.CreateUser(` it have only standard method signatures and if I override `CreateUser()` of my provider my method won't show up in the list.

Comment: How about using extension methods?

Comment: @keni how can I use extension method here? I'm not calling neither base class nor my extended class directly, but call it via Membership wrapper rather. I think I only need to cast it correctly, but I'm lost at the moment

Comment: If you look in the debugger at the return type, can't you see the correct one to cast to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do correct casting, so here it is:

custom membership provider:

```
public sealed class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider {...}
```

custom membership user:

```
public class CustomMembershipUser : MembershipUser {...}
```

To create new custom user:

```
CustomMembershipProvider myProvider = (CustomMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
CustomMembershipUser user = (CustomMembershipUser)myProvider.CreateUser(...);
```

To get custom user:

```
CustomMembershipProvider myProvider = CustomMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
CustomMembershipUser user = (CustomMembershipUser)myProvider.GetUser(...);
```

And this article shows how to implement custom user: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of extending the `MembershipUser` you can add additional Profile data to the user.

For example the following the following can be added to your configuration file.

```
<profile>
    <properties>
        <add name="FirstName"/>
        <add name="LastName"/>
        <add name="Address"/>
        <add name="City"/>
        <add name="State"/>
        <add name="Zip"/>
    <properties>
<profile>
```

This will let ASP.NET create a `ProfileCommon` class and that will include all the properties you specify in the configuration file.

[Here is the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) for the `Profile` Properties.

Comment: Profile data is not related to membership provider and I would prefer to keep all user data in one place. Besides I think I'm close to the solution. I need to figure out how to cast it correctly.